# Парное тире в сочетании с запятой и знаком вопроса

Tags: пунктуация

Вот написал в другом вопросе фразу:

*Я с трудом перевариваю сочетание "социальная сеть" - в русском есть нормальное слово "публичный", чем оно-то не подошло?(,) - но смирился.*

и умер от собственной пунктуации. Не нашел ничего лучше, как заменить тире на скобки. А если все-таки тире оставить, существует ли вариант нефантастической пунктуации?! Формально по правилам знак вопроса может существовать при парном тире, но ведь и запятую в такой конструкции нельзя опускать, она ставится по мотивам разделения составляющих в сложносочиненном предложении?!

Comment: А мне вариант со скобками понравился. Это же явно вставная конструкция со своими знаками препинания, скобки - лучший выбор.

Comment: @Людмила, так вопрос не стоит. Я не корректор и не ищу легких путей для оправдания собственной безграмотности или пунктуационной лакуны. Есть некоторая пунктуационная заморочка, мне интересно, что думают о ней правила, а не как её обойти. Примеров можно подобрать много, да и не каждый автор согласиться на скобки, если не будет четко сказано, что парное тире здесь **недопустимо** по таким-то и таким-то причинам.. А если допустимо, то как быть со знаками?!

Answer (score 1):

Похожий пример есть у Лопатина: Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название? — но всё не попадается (Щерб.).

Здесь запятая, которая была на месте вставки перед союзом НО, опускается.

Сравнить (без вопросительного знака, перенесенная запятая):
Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название, — но всё не попадается (Щерб.).

Comment: *Здесь запятая, которая была на месте вставки перед союзом НО, опускается* - Отлично, спасибо. Это логично и понятно. Но найти бы еще четкое указание (у Лопатина или еще где), что да, именно опускается, и исчерпывающий критерий, когда именно опускается.

Comment: Забавно. Все этот пример цитируют (даже у нас на ресурсе - в очень похожем вопросе, на который я сам же и отвечал ))))), но вот у Лопатина я его не нашёл )))). Кстати, разница все-таки есть... Там, "Щерб", однородные сказуемые, у меня два предложения в ССП.

Answer (score 0):

*Я с трудом перевариваю сочетание "социальная сеть", - в русском есть нормальное слово "публичный", чем оно-то не подошло? - но смирился.*

Думаю, что такой вариант вполне приемлем.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, я понял. Тут действительно ограничение на допустимость. Парное тире нельзя использовать в конце предложения (в начале, естественно, тоже) - некуда второе тире ставить, не перед точкой же? Видимо, это надо распространить и на абсолютный конец составляющих сложных предложений, причем, очевидно, и ССП и СПП. Иначе вот такая-то дурь получается. А скобки всегда выручат. Как-то так.